# HTML/Javascript/Bootstrap Webpage Does Not Display Text Until I Use Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, tomcat

I'm making a Tomcat and JavEE web app, but for the front end I am using a free javascript + html template. I am using a JSP with JSTL in place of html files, and including the javascript and other resources in tomcat 8.5/webapp.

However, when I call the JSP, I have this weird problem where the text that I display does not show up unless I click inspect element.

This happens on all browsers.

I think it might be some problem with the way that JSP/JavaEE works with javascript, because the template works fine when it is not used as a javaEE project.

Does anyone know common problems that cause this?

Comment: What browser? And what's the free template you're using?

Comment: Both Edge and Chrome seem to have the same problem. The template can be found here: https://freehtml5.co/neat-free-html5-bootstrap-website-template-for-portfolio/